# Encryption/Decryption of XML on user machine

Tags: java, xml, encryption

I have an XML file which I want to store on the users machine. I want this file to be encrypted, so that the user won't use/understand the data.  When required, this encrypted file will get decrypted and the front-end will read it and use the data. For front-end and Encryption/Decryption I will be using Java.

I need some suggestion on how to do this.  Greenhorn in cryptography.

What can be the best approach?

Comment: If your app. can decrypt the file, the user can reverse engineer the app. and then decrypt it themselves.

Comment: @Andrew - thats the reason, why I asked techie guys.. ;) I know some one can do the same. I just want to make it troublesome for him and her(if girls do like this kinda job) to decode/decrypt..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encryption is very, very easy to do wrong. Wrong in case of encryption means that making a single mistake can break your whole encryption scheme.

When thinking about employing encryption, it's almost always (except in cases of professional security developers) a good idea to use the solutions the provider of your framework did for you. Java offers the cryptography extensions which you can start with [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html). There are some good examples for using it [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#Examples).

Comment: +1 : even professional can get it wrong, so you're *destined* to get it wrong if you try to reinvent the wheel and create your own cryptographic method.

Comment: @0xCAFEBASE - Thanks.. I tried an Java example for the same. But it is creating rather renaming the encrypted file with .des extension. The Decryptor code again renames it to .xml, removing the .des extension. Though, this sample code encrypts the file..I want to know is this the right idea..?

Comment: To answer that, one would need to know what it is that you're actually trying to accomplish. There are different things requested under "encryption", and it's not always to strengthen the security of the data. Sometimes it's to obfuscate, sometimes it's to have another well-sounding line on the product sheet. Sometimes people mean "authentication" when saying "encryption". It's hard to tell from the known parameters what the scenario is that you want to protect against or that you want to accomplish.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE - Thanks... My application will be using data stored in XML files and I want to protect it from direct use, either by users or by other product developers. Have a nice day - John

Answer (score 0):

You could use a base64 encoder/decoder if you want just to prevent viewing or/and editing your XML files directly.

It's not the best possible solution concerning security, but it would work if you want something easy and quick.

Comment: Whilst this will obscure the text, base64 encoding is not encryption of the data. It will be possible for a user with some technical knowledge (or an attacker) to decode the data again.

Comment: @John Krommidas - Thanks for your reply. But the comment by cywyllie says that base64 encoding won't solve the issue.